# How to parse syntax using OWL API? Java

Tags: java, owl

I am a beginner in OWL API and am learning how to parse functional syntax. So far I have been unable to do it, and cannot figure out where I am going wrong. For example, consider a short and simple OWL file having the following(just a random example) -

EquivalentClasses(:TestPizza ObjectIntersectionOf(DataMinCardinality(20 :hasToppingValue xsd:double) :Pizza))

The problem is I can't even create an OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser variable since it is showing undefined( I am using the latest version - 5.1.18).

Could anyone help by providing a code example on how to parse it?

Comment: Well:
 the for loop in showinfo() loops to the end of the vector; that taxpayer's info is returned. You call that function n times: n times the last taxpayer is returned ;-). Perhaps you intended originally to print in that function? Otherwise you need either an index parameter (which payer's info) or assemble a string that contains all lines.

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: I wrote a short answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a function

```
string showinfo(size_t i) {
        string info = taxPayers[i].taxpayerId + " " + taxPayers[i].name + " " +
            taxPayers[i].address + " " + taxPayers[i].postcode;
        return info;
}
```

and call that with

```
for (int i = 0; i < taxPayers.taxPayers.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "[" << i << "] - " << taxPayers.showinfo(i) << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Glad to make you happy, man! ;-)

Comment: Love you ;-) <3